# JavaScript Number to Letter

Tags: javascript

I have recently been trying to code a problem where some JS code converts a letter to a number, eg. 1=a.

My current code looks like this (using a HTML script tag):

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Begin
    function convert(input) {
        var inputlength = input.length;
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        var phonenumber = "";
        for (i = 0; i < inputlength; i++) {
            var character = input.charAt(i);

            switch (character) {
                case '0':
                    phonenumber += "0";
                    break


                case 'a':
                    phonenumber += "1 ";
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    phonenumber += "2 ";
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    phonenumber += "3 ";
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    phonenumber += "4 ";
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    phonenumber += "5 ";
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    phonenumber += "6 ";
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    phonenumber += "7 ";
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    phonenumber += "8 ";
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    phonenumber += "9 ";
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    phonenumber += "10 ";
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    phonenumber += "11 ";
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    phonenumber += "12 ";
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    phonenumber += "13 ";
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    phonenumber += "14 ";
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    phonenumber += "15 ";
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    phonenumber += "16 ";
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    phonenumber += "17 ";
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    phonenumber += "18 ";
                    break;
                case 's':
                    phonenumber += "19 ";
                    break;
                case 't':
                    phonenumber += "20 ";
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    phonenumber += "21 ";
                    break;
                case 'v':
                    phonenumber += "22 ";
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    phonenumber += "23 ";
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    phonenumber += "24 ";
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    phonenumber += "25 ";
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    phonenumber += "26 ";
                    break;


                case '-':
                    phonenumber += "-";
                    break;
                case '1':
                    phonenumber += "a";
                    break;
                case '2':
                    phonenumber += "b";
                    break;
                case '3':
                    phonenumber += "c";
                    break;
                case '4':
                    phonenumber += "d";
                    break;
                case '5':
                    phonenumber += "e";
                    break;
                case '6':
                    phonenumber += "f";
                    break;
                case '7':
                    phonenumber += "g";
                    break;
                case '8':
                    phonenumber += "h";
                    break;
                case '9':
                    phonenumber += "i";
                    break;
                case '1-0':
                    phonenumber += "j";
                    break;
                case '1-1':
                    phonenumber += "k";
                    break;
                case '1-2':
                    phonenumber += "l";
                    break;
                case '1-3':
                    phonenumber += "m";
                    break;
                case '1-4':
                    phonenumber += "n";
                    break;
                case '1-5':
                    phonenumber += "o";
                    break;
                case '1-6':
                    phonenumber += "p";
                    break;
                case '1-7':
                    phonenumber += "q";
                    break;
                case '1-8':
                    phonenumber += "r";
                    break;
                case '1-9':
                    phonenumber += "s";
                    break;
                case '2-0':
                    phonenumber += "t";
                    break;
                case '2-1':
                    phonenumber += "u";
                    break;
                case '2-2':
                    phonenumber += "v";
                    break;
                case '2-3':
                    phonenumber += "w";
                    break;
                case '2-4':
                    phonenumber += "x";
                    break;
                case '2-5':
                    phonenumber += "y";
                    break;
                case '2-6':
                    phonenumber += "z";
                    break;

            }
        }
        document.myform.number.value = phonenumber;
        return true;
    }
    //  End -->
</script>
<form name=myform>
    <table border=0>
        <tr>
            <td>Alphanumeric #:</td>
            <td>
                <input type=text size=20 maxlength=20 name=alphabet value="Will123">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Converted #:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size=20 maxlength=20 name="number">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center colspan=2>
                <input type=button value="Convert" onClick="return    convert(document.myform.alphabet.value)">
            </td>
    </table>
</form>

</html>
```

However whenever I try to convert a number corresponing to, say, x (24) to a letter, it gives me "bd" because it is processing the 2 and 4 separately. Is there an easy way to stop this, so that when I type in 24, it produces "x"?

Comment: `input.charAt(i);` return 1 char at a time

Comment: What's your input, just `24`? If there are more numbers, how are they separated?

Comment: so the input can be numbers as well as characters ?

Comment: what is your expected converted output of `Will123` ?

Comment: 23-9-12-12- is what the converter produces

Comment: Your switch statement uses a single character, but the case statement checks for multiple characters "2-6".  How does that work?

Comment: I was half way through trying to get the converter to recognise the figures seperately and never got round to finishing it

Comment: Yes, that's what it produces *now*, but what John is asking is what you *want* it to produce.

Comment: the Will123 produced exactly what I wanted it to

Comment: Yet, given a simple input like "Will123" it could be [1,2,3] or [12,3] or [1,23] and each would produce a different result.  The requirements are not very clear.

Comment: x gives you 2-4. 2-4 gives you x. see my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through the input, you are calling `input.charAt(i)`, but this will only pull one character at a time. If you want it to pull a two digit number, you need to write the code to do so. Otherwise, the number is read and processed one digit at a time.

When you pull the individual character, check and see if it is between 0 and 9, inclusive. If it is, loop through the next couple characters and build the desired string before passing it into the `switch`, that way you can get the desired multi-digit input.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following :

```
function covert(input)
{
    var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var nums=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","1-0","1-1","1-2","1-3","1-4","1-5","1-6","1-7,"1-8","1-9","2-0","2-1",2-2","2-3","2-4",2-5",2-6"]
    var letters = input.lowerCase().split("");

    for(var i=0;i<letters.length;i++)
       if(letters[i].lowerCase != letters[i].toUpperCase()) //Checking if it's a letter 
          phonenumber+=toString(alphabet.indexOf(letter[i])+1;);


    var dashesAndNum=input.replace(/[A-Za-z],' ').split(" ");

    for(var i=0;i<dashesAndNum.length;i++)
       if(dashesAndNum[i] == "0" || dashesAndNum[i] == "-")
          phonenumber+=dashesAndNum[i];
       else
          phonenumber+=alphabet[num.indexOf(dashesAndNum[i])];

    document.myform.number.value = phonenumber;
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the idea of `-` between generated numbers. That means, you can not code something with `-` surrounded by a digit.

```
function convert(input) {
    var inputlength = input.length,
        CODE = '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        phonenumber = "",
        character,
        i;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < inputlength; i++) {
        character = input[i];
        if (isFinite(input[i]) && '-' === input[i + 1] && isFinite(input[i+2])) {
            i += 2;
            character += input[i];
        }
        phonenumber += ~CODE.indexOf(character) ? ('' + CODE.indexOf(character)).split('').join('-') : (character === '-' ? '-' : CODE[character]);
    }
    document.myform.number.value = phonenumber;
    return true;
}
```

A proper solution to overcome the problem with `-` is to implement a different character as sign for 2-digit numbers, maybe a `|` so the code looks like this:

```
function convert(input) {
    var inputlength = input.length,
        CODE= '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        SEPARATOR = '|',
        phonenumber = "",
        character,
        i;

    input = input.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < inputlength; i++) {
        character = input[i];
        if (isFinite(input[i]) && SEPARATOR === input[i + 1] && isFinite(input[i + 2])) {
            i += 2;
            character += input[i];
        }
        phonenumber += ~CODE.indexOf(character) ? ('' + CODE.indexOf(character)).split('').join(SEPARATOR) : (character === '-' ? '-' : CODE[character]);
    }
    document.myform.number.value = phonenumber;
    return true;
}
```